# Dygraph rollperiod box plotted on top and not changeable

Tags: dygraphs

Dygraph roll period box is plotting on top of the graph and I cannot click on it to change the values. See http://www.wisbuoynet.com/BuoyData/BBB/2017/WTemp/WTempDG3.html

Does anyone know why this is happening? This code is essentially directly from dygraph site

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv"
  style="width:800px; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    g= new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "temperatures.csv", 
    {
     rollPeriod: 10,
     showRoller: true,
            }
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That link 404s.

Comment: also, it should be `<link href=...>`, not `<link src=...>`.